# Where does views's template files get saved?

Tags: views, theming, 8

I have created a view for content type = "`Article`" and have chosen "**FORMAT**" = GRID

**FORMAT**

**Format**:Grid | Settings

**Show**:Fields | Settings

My question is where does this view related template get saved?

I know Views default templates are located under "/core/modules/views/templates/" folder.

Here is the basic GRID template. How this grid template recognize a specific view that can render fields only of "ARTICLE" content type?

Is there any other template formed using view's machine name and row style?

Where should I place any view template so that it can effect all views of specific content type like "Article".

Answer (score 0):

> Where should I place any view template so that it can effect all views
>   of specific content type like "Article".

While you can do this with nodes, I don't believe it's possible on views to affect all views of `x` content type. As you can see in FILTERS, there is a Type filter (=Article). It's just a filter.

The best option you have is to make it affect a specific view name and a view display.

EX: **views-view-grid--[view-name].html.twig**

if you want to specify a display then **views-view-grid--[view-name]--[[machine-name]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbNIb.jpg).html.twig**

Then you copy the code from core's views-view-grid.html and paste it on your template file and modify as you wish.

If you want to alter fields, then use **views-view-fields--[view-name]--[[machine-name]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbNIb.jpg).html.twig**

You place your custom template files in `/themes/[Your Theme]/templates` folder.

Comment: And where should I place this file? I mean in which folder should I put it?

Comment: @SugandhKhanna goes inside your theme's templates folder

Comment: Will it work if I place this twig template file inside my custom module with proper naming conventions?

Comment: @SugandhKhanna it won't. For module, you might be able to do it using [hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Render!theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter/8.2.x) Here is an article on how to create a [template for a view filter](https://www.chapterthree.com/blog/how-to-create-custom-theme-suggestions-drupal-8) might help you figure out how to do it for the actual view.